# Why is my if(else if) statement being ignored?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public void stackPower(int stackAmount)
{
    super.stackPower(stackAmount);

    if (this.amount == -1) {
        this.amount = -2;
        }
    else if (this.amount == -2) {
        this.amount = -3;
    }
    if (this.amount == -3) {
        this.amount = -4;
    }

}
```

During testing value goes from -1 to -2 to -4 to -6 etc.

What I want to happen: goes from -1 to -2 to -3 to -4 and then stops.

Could someone explain what I am missing here and how to fix my issue? Thanks.

Comment: The third one isn't a else-if.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What is the default value in the `amount` variable?

Comment: Is the point just to subtract 1 from amount?  If so you could just subtract 1 so long as it isn't equal to -4 (assuming that's where you wanted to stop).

Comment: What is the default value in the `amount` variable and are you using this in a loop?, if so post the loop block togethe with your question.

Comment: @preciousbetine

the amount variable is -1, and I am not using this in a loop.

Comment: What's in the superclass?

Answer (score 1):

Your third `if` condition is missing an `else` (but could just as easily be an `else` block). Like,

```
if (this.amount == -1) {
    this.amount = -2;
} else if (this.amount == -2) {
    this.amount = -3;
} else {
    this.amount = -4;
}
```

But, I would *simplify* the logic with a call to `Math.max(int, int)` like

```
this.amount = Math.max(-4, this.amount - 1);
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I had my code like this prior to changing it to what you see in my post. It doesn't fix the issue completely unfortunately. (it does not exceed -4, but jumps from -2 to -4 still.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (this.amount == -1) {
        this.amount = -2;
    }
    else if (this.amount == -2) {
        this.amount = -3;
    }
```

I think the `else if` clause will never be executed, because, once the `if` clause is executed, the `else` clause wille never be executed.

Comment: this way the else if clause does get executed, but any other if (or else if) statement after it will just override it.

Comment: `int i=1;
        if(i==1) {
         i=2;
        }else if(i==2){
         i=3;
        }
        System.out.println(i);` gives me a `2`

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing the else if into an if should fix the problem.

The issue you're having is because when you have an if-statement and an else-if, if we go into the if-statement we jump over subsequent else-if statements or else statements.

```
     public void stackPower(int stackAmount)
{
          super.stackPower(stackAmount);

    if (this.amount == -1) {
        this.amount = -2;
        }
    if (this.amount == -2) {
        this.amount = -3;
    }
    if (this.amount == -3) {
        this.amount = -4;
    }

}
```